# Test (unittest, mock) if a global variable list is updated

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock, python-unittest.mock

file.py:

```
GLOB_VAR = []

def my_func(x, msg):
    if x:
        logging.warning(msg)
    GLOB_VAR.append(x)
```

test.py:

```
@patch('file.GLOB_VAR', [])
@patch('logging.Logger.warning')
def test_file_with_msg(self, logging):
    x = 'test_x'
    msg = 'test_msg'

    my_func(x=x, msg=msg)
    logging.assert_called_with(message)
    assert x in GLOB_VAR
```

I always get an AssertionError. from the line `assert x in GLOB_VAR`

Let me say that I DO need a global variable

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I shouldn't have patched the global variable as I need to assert against the file's global variable and not against the a mock's instance global variable.

This does does the trick:

test.py

```
from file import my_func, GLOB_VAR

@patch('logging.Logger.warning')
def test_file_with_msg(self, logging):
    x = 'test_x'
    msg = 'test_msg'

    my_func(x=x, msg=msg)
    logging.assert_called_with(message)
    assert x in GLOB_VAR
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that you *really* need a global variable.